# When I use sftp in script, prompt ask me the password, which I want to be done from the script

Tags: shell

I am writing the shell script, using sftp command.

```
#!/bin/sh    

sftp @user@hostname    

cd @dir    

get file    
exit 0
```

Unfortunately, when I execute the script, the prompt says:

```
$ password:
```

However, I don't want to see this prompt, I want to use it inside the script.
Could you help me , please?

Thanks, Oleg

Comment: even though it's sftp, it's still just ssh under the hood. set up a passwordless login for ssh as that user and sftp will "just work".

Comment: @MarcB sftp will "just work" but this script will still not work. `sftp` does not start a remote session that can be controlled like that.

Comment: sftp starts an interactive session, it will not drop the running script into a session that can be controlled. You cannot use it like this. You can use the `-b` flag to give it a series of commands though.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect and run command in one command line, without being prompted for password, you can use the command **lftp**.